# Truncate sentences in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, truncate

I've got a helper that I'm using to truncate strings in Rails, and it works great when I truncate sentences that end in periods. How should I modify the code to also truncate sentences when they end in question marks or exclamation points?

```
def smart_truncate(s, opts = {})
    opts = {:words => 12}.merge(opts)
    if opts[:sentences]
      return s.split(/\.(\s|$)+/).reject{ |s| s.strip.empty? }[0, opts[:sentences]].map{|s| s.strip}.join('. ') + '...'
    end
    a = s.split(/\s/) # or /[ ]+/ to only split on spaces
    n = opts[:words]
    a[0...n].join(' ') + (a.size > n ? '... (more)' : '')
end
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Any reason for not using this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

Comment: Have you considered using `truncate`, provided by Rails?

Comment: I considered using truncate but it doesn't suit my needs. I'm using this helper to give a preview of content without spoiling it (being too long) and showing an entire sentence is what I've settled on.

Comment: That's what the `:separator` option is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the [`truncate` method](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate)

```
'Once upon a time in a world far far away'.truncate(27, separator: /\s/, ommission: "....")
```

which will return `"Once upon a time in a..."`

---

And if you need to truncate by number of words instead then use the newly introduced [`truncate_words`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate_words) (since Rails 4.2.2)

```
'And they found that many people were sleeping better.'.truncate_words(5, omission: '... (continued)')
```

which returns

```
"And they found that many... (continued)"
```